# Avoid using multiple time the same url in the appsettings

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core, microservices, appsettings

I have a microservices solution and three appsettings per project, the problem is that I have the same URL many times and it is difficult to change it everywhere each time, so I wonder if I can replace these URLs with an environment variable or something like that, so I can change the URL if needed only once.

An example of my configuration:

[image: My project structure]

[image: eg of an appsettings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so I wonder if I can replace these URLs with an environment variable or something like that

Yes, you can totally do that! In fact, the default `WebHostBuilder` (and `HostBuilder` starting with 3.0) actually set up the configuration in a way that there are multiple configuration sources being used.

The following application configuration sources will be read in order [by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#default-configuration):

1. General configuration from `appsettings.json`
2. Environment-specific configuration from `appsettings.<environment>.json`
3. Development user secrets (if running under the Development environment)
4. Environment variables
5. Command line arguments

Configuration sources that come later can overwrite values from earlier sources. That’s why you can specify a good default in `appsettings.json` for example, and overwrite it for an environment-specific value in `appsettings.Production.json`.

The same is true for the environment variables, which are incorporated by default. You can just set environment variables with the *right key* that will then overwrite the values from your appsettings files.

For example, to overwrite the `IdentityServerBaseUrl` from your example, you have to first think about what the full configuration path of that setting is. For the JSON configuration, you basically have to combine every key down to the actual value with a colon. So in this case, the configuration path would be `AdminConfiguration:IdentityServerBaseUrl`.

Because colons are a bit difficult to use as keys in environment variables, you can replace it by two underscores. So the environment variable you can set to overwrite the value from your appsettings file is `AdminConfiguration__IdentityServerBaseUrl`:

```
set AdminConfiguration__IdentityServerBaseUrl=http://10.0.75.1:5000
```

The same works for all configuration values within your file.

You could also expand the default configuration setup and add additional configuration providers. For example, you could add *another* file, e.g. `appsettings.global.json` which contains configuration values that applies to all applications and which you can then share between all applications. To do that, you just have to expand the default builder:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
        {
            config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.global.json", optional: true);
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of ways to do it.

**Shared Config**

You can create shared configuration at parent level and load it in each project at start up. You can find more about and how to implement here [Shared Config](https://andrewlock.net/sharing-appsettings-json-configuration-files-between-projects-in-asp-net-core/)

**External Configuration Store Pattern**

A better way especially in prod, You can save the configuration in external stores like Azure Key Vault or  [Azure App configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this nuget package that will allow you to use the same value in multiple keys
https://www.nuget.org/packages/TemplateFormattedConfiguration/